# How could I do parameter tuning with feature selection in R package mlr?

Tags: survival, mlr

In this project, I am trying to tune the parameters(especially the step number parameter) of the CoxBoost model for survival analysis. I have more features than samples and many features are highly correlated. So I made a filtering function which allows me to do an initial feature selection. The next step, I want to find the optimal parameter for my model. How could I achieve that?

**Codes without initial selection**

```
ps = makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("stepno", values = c(50,70,100,150,200))
)
ctrl = makeTuneControlGrid()
rdesc=makeResampleDesc("RepCV",folds=3L,reps=20L, predict = "both")
 res = tuneParams("surv.CoxBoost", task = surv.task, resampling =
 rdesc, par.set = ps, control = ctrl)
```

**Codes with initial selection**

```
ps = makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("stepno", values = c(50,70,100,150,200))
)
ctrl = makeTuneControlGrid()
rdesc=makeResampleDesc("RepCV",folds=3L,reps=20L, predict = "both")
lrn = makeTuneWrapper("surv.CoxBoost", resampling = rdesc,
par.set = ps, control = ctrl, show.info = FALSE)
lrn1 = makeFilterWrapper(learner = lrn, fw.method = 
"uni.cor.filter",fw.threshold=0.5)
res = tuneParams(lrn1, task = surv.task, resampling =
rdesc, par.set = ps, control = ctrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lrn = makeFilterWrapper("surv.CoxBoost", fw.method = "uni.cor.filter",fw.threshold=0.5)
lrn1 = makeTuneWrapper(lrn, 
         resampling = makeResampleDesc("RepCV",folds=3L,reps=20L),
         par.set = makeParamSet(
                    makeDiscreteParam("stepno", values = c(50,70,100,150,200))), 
         control = makeTuneControlGrid(), 
         show.info = T)
r = resample(lrn1, surv.task, 
         resampling = makeFixedHoldoutInstance(train.inds = 1:74, test.inds = 1:74, 
                        size = 74), 
         models = TRUE)
```

Here, when doing the outer resampling, I use the whole data as your train dataset and test dataset. In this way, we can get a comparison among tuning parameters.